# How to remove only the characters inside brackets [ ] from a string?

Tags: applescript

So I have been searching for hours on how to do this via AppleScript and I see no post about it.

Basically, I have the following string:

> @junior_cat23, [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]

I want the script to remove only this part:

> , [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]

So I am left only with:

> @junior_cat23

I am using "AppleScript's text item delimiters" but the problem is that it will also remove the characters from the text I want to keep.

This is the script I am using:

```
set theName to "@junior_cat23, [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]"

tell application "Finder"
    
    -- Remove Characters
    
    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set the_strings_to_strip to {"[", "]", "-", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"}
    
    set the_files to theName
    repeat with a_file in the_files
        set the_name to theName
        repeat with I from 1 to count of the_strings_to_strip
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to item I of the_strings_to_strip
            set the_text_items to text items of the_name
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
            set the_name to the_text_items as string
        end repeat
    end repeat
    
    -- Remove Preceding and Trailing Spaces in String
    
    set trimName to "echo \"" & the_text_items & "\" | xargs"
    set nameTrimmed to (do shell script trimName)
end tell
```

I get the following result:

> "@_,"

I just want to remove the characters in side of the brackets and keep the others. I will appreciate a solution that does not require a handler since I will be using the script with an application that does not accept handlers.

Comment: Wow that was quick. Thank you so much. I can't believe that a simple solution like this is so hard to find.

Comment: Please include all requirements when asking a question! Do not introduce secondary variables after the fact!

Comment: What if I have multiple names, for example "@junior_cat23 @james_cat24 [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]" and I want to keep both of them while the string does not have commas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

This is the most straight forward method to accomplish the goal:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set theName to "@junior_cat23, [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]"

set theName to ¬
    characters 1 thru ¬
        ((offset of "," in theName) - 1) ¬
            of theName as string
```

Result:

```
@junior_cat23
```

To address the comment:

> What if I have multiple names, for example "@junior_cat23 @james_cat24 [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]" and I want to keep both of them while the string does not have commas?

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
set theName to "@junior_cat23 @james_cat24 [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]"

set theName to ¬
    characters 1 thru ¬
        ((offset of "[" in theName) - 2) ¬
            of theName as string
```

Result:

```
@junior_cat23 @james_cat24
```

---

**Original Answer**

One of the reasons you were not getting returned what you wanted is in some cases **AppleScript** is case insensitive and wrapping the `-- Remove Characters` *code* in a `considering case` *block* handles some of the issues, but not all. Additionally, since you have numeric characters in both what you want retained and not, then as currently coded it removes all numeric characters.

While your current *code* could be reworked, I'm not inclined to do that as from both deleted comments and still existing comments you've left out vital information in the OP. That said, I'll assume for the moment that all target *strings* will have either `, [ ... ]` or  `[ ... ]` that needs to be removed and the following `sed` *command* handles the example *value* of `theName` *variable* in your OP and in the comments.

So whether you have:

```
set theName to "@junior_cat23, [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]"
```

Or:

```
set theName to "@junior_cat23 @james_cat24 [ID]-[E9B-Z8X-H1V-722]"
```

Then:

```
do shell script "sed -E -e 's|\\[.*||' -e 's|,||g' -e 's|^[ ]+||' -e 's|[ ]+$||'<<<" & theName's quoted form
```

<sup>• Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full code.</sup>

Returns:

```
@junior_cat23
```

Or:

```
@junior_cat23 @james_cat24
```

Without any leading/trailing *spaces*.

---

Understanding the `do shell script` and `sed` *commands*:

- `do shell script` -- Executes a shell script using the **sh** shell.
- `sed` -- Stream Editor.
- `-E` -- Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE’s). The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.
- `−e` *command* -- Append the *editing commands* specified by the *command argument* to the list of *commands*.
- `'s|\\[.*||'` -- Removes everything from the first `[` *character* to the end of the *line*.
- `'s|,||g'` -- Removes all *commas*, if they exist.
- `'s|^[ ]+||'` -- Removes all *leading spaces*, if they exist.
- `'s|[ ]+$||'` -- Removes all *trailing spaces*, if they exist.
- `<<<` -- **Here Strings** - A variant of **here documents**, the format is: `[n]<<< word` - The word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal. Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed. The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended, to the command on its standard input (or file descriptor *n* if *n* is specified).
- `& theName's quoted form` -- Appends the single quoted *value* of the *variable* `theName` to the end of the *command line* of the `sed` *command* in the `do shell script` *command* so as not to expand any *shell special characters* in the *value* of the *variable* `theName`, if any exists.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I should have word it like you did: "all target strings will have either , [ ... ] or [ ... ]". Basically I just want to remove everything in the brackets and this does the job.

Comment: @David, I've added an "Understanding the `do shell script` and `sed` _commands_" section at the end of the answer.

Comment: Good work!  Straight to the reading list! Vote up!